# Writing to JSON File

Tags: python, json

This code writes to json file test when I specify the parameter values directly.

```
import json

def write_to_json(list, filename):
   f = open(filename, "w")
   json.dump(list, f)
   f.close()
   return
write_to_json(["a", "b"], "test.json")
```

However when the list is from return statement from previous function, it does not write.

```
def write_to_json(list, filename):
   f = open(filename,"w")
   json.dump(list, f)
   f.close()
   return

write_to_json(list,"test.json")

Error: Unresolved reference "list"
```

Comment: I don't see a `list=whatever` anywhere (*terrible* name to use for a variable BTW!) -- show us your **whole** code if you want help finding bugs!

Comment: list is an builtin variable don't use that.

Comment: @ Alex, list was from return statement from previous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

def foo(bar):
    return [bar]

def write_to_json(list, filename):
   f=open(filename,"w")
   json.dump(list, f)
   f.close()
   return

mylst = foo('bar')
write_to_json(mylst,'t.txt')
```

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code above.
It's most likely that you did not specify what `list` is.

Comment: This solves the problem. I was assuming list has values in it.